# Android null object reference on getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener

Tags: android, arrays, exception, layout, null

i need to check if a layout has been completely inflated before doing an operation, for that, I'm using the code below that has a semaphore that waits until a two specifics buttons is inflated. The code works fine most of the time but sometimes I get the Fatal Exception error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference. Does anyone know why and how to fix it? Here is code and  the complete log:

```
    final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
    LayoutKBDReferencesHelper.instance().
            getLayoutKBDReferences().getBtn0().
            getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        semaphore.release();
                    }
                });
    try {
        semaphore.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

final Semaphore semaphore1 = new Semaphore(0);
    LayoutKBDReferencesHelper.instance().getLayoutKBDReferences().getBtn1().
            getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        semaphore1.release();
                    }
                });
    try {
        semaphore1.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Log:

```html
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver$CopyOnWriteArray.add(ViewTreeObserver.java:1181)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.java:550)
at com.example.layout.SampleLayout.showKBD(SampleLayout.java:1025)
at com.example.layout.SampleLayout.OutputCallbacks.Text(OutputCallbacks.java:108)
at com.example.layout.SampleLayout.Base.Text(SourceFile:5)
at com.example.layout.SampleLayout.LayoutTest(SourceFile)
at com.example.layout.SampleLayout.LayoutTest(SourceFile:4)
at com.example.layout.SampleLayout.LayoutTest(SourceFile:1)
at com.example.layout.SampleLayout.SampleLayout$4.run(SampleLayout.java:378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the full stack trace?

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi, unfortunately, I do not have the full stack trace. This fatal exception was caught in analytics

Comment: Your stack trace suggests that you are doing this work in some callback, and that callback is being executed after the activity is destroyed.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have any idea what I can do in this case? Because I don't have much control over this method since it's from the Android SDK itself. Or if I know of another way to check if a button has already been inflated in the layout.. so I could change this code

Comment: You do not appear to be unregistering your `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` objects. Try doing that in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: @JulianaMiranda did you ever figure anything out? I'm having this crash but none of my code is on the stack trace and I don't use `ViewTreeObserver`.